# How to get error message in nant.onfailure

Tags: nant

I'm trying to get the build's failed message in `nant.onfailure`. I Know that I can use `try/ catch` but I'd like to avoid this route. Is it possible get the failed message without `try/catch`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are aware for NAntContrib library.

http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/

You can include their library to get extra sets of 'Tasks'. I am current using task called "record" to do the logging upon success and failure without any try/catch s.

Something like,

```
<property name="Build.FailureLog" value="C:\TestLog.txt" />

<!-- Start the listener record -->
<record name="${Build.FailureLog}" level="Verbose" action="Start" />
<property name="nant.onfailure" value="Failure" />

<target name="Failure" description="This target is called upon when the build has failed." >
    <!-- Close the listener -->
    <record name="${Build.FailureLog}" action="Close" />

    <!-- Additionally you could send emails by including in mail -->
</target>
```